# Konsole closes after few 10 minutes

Tags: 16.04, konsole

After kernel update to 4.4.0-92-generic #115-Ubuntu SMP (16.04.3 LTS), I noticed that konsole app terminates (without notification) after 10 mins when there is no activity on konsole(like typing etc). It looks like there is a timeout on it but I can't figure out how to fix it!

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please boot into the previous kernel and see if the issue vanishes or persists? Thanks.

Comment: It still did with 4.4.0-91.

Comment: In that case the cause is not the kernel upgrade.

Comment: Yes, you may be right. I have googled for answers but no luck. It's getting annoying since I usually work with multiply konsoles.

Comment: Did you look through the Konsole configuration and your shell start-up files for anything that kills the console after prolonged inactivity? Are the terminal sessions local or remote (e. g. via SSH)?